# 100% Width collapsing horizontally?

Tags: html, css

Two `DIV` elements which appear in the below HTML are losing their 100% width as per the CSS when the browser is made smaller?

Can anyone shed some light as to how to resolve this issue?

Thanks,

**HTML**

```
<div class="featured">    
    <h1>Name <span class="desc">This is a sample</span></h1>
</div>

<div class="aquabar">
    <div class="aquacont">
        Sample Description
        <h2>Some more information that is applicable</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.featured {
    width: 100%
    height: 400px;
    background-image: url("../img/featured-image.jpg");
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 40 0 0 0;
}
.aquabar {
    width: 100%
    height: 100px;
    background-image: url("../img/featured-bg.jpg"); 
    background-color: #49aca9;
    margin: -30px 0 30px 0;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/anzvonba/ - works for me.

Comment: @Lisa Jaffe, its working fine on chrome and firefox. Can you specify on which browser you are viewing?

Comment: This only happens to me when I make it so small that the 'sample' text doesn't fit, and this is normal behaviour, use overflow:hidden; if you don't want it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `box-sizing:border-box` for your 100% div. So that it will understand 100% is including your padding/margin.

```
 .featured {
width: 100%
height: 400px;
background-image: url("../img/featured-image.jpg");
text-transform: uppercase;
padding: 40 0 0 0;
box-sizing:border-box;
}
.aquabar {
width: 100%
height: 100px;
background-image: url("../img/featured-bg.jpg"); 
background-color: #49aca9;
margin: -30px 0 30px 0;
box-sizing:border-box;
}
```